# Magento2 - Cron readiness check failure

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.2.2, permissions, log

Cron is not working properly showing error in `/var/www/domain.com/var/log/update.log`

```
[2019-09-25 07:07:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /var/www/domain.com/bin/magento [] []
```

There is already pemission to `bin/magento` file.

log in file `/var/www/domain.com/var/log/.update_cronjob_status`

```
{
    "readiness_checks": {
        "error": "<br/>Found non-writable path(s):<br/>/var/www/domain.com/bin/magento",
        "file_permissions_verified": false
    },
    "last_timestamp": 1569386101,
    "current_timestamp": 1569386522
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is an Permission issue. You can Manage it by this way:**

Keep the whole project permission as 644 and

```
find /desired_location -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
find /desired_location -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
```

Also Set User to your

```
chown -R Username:Username .
```

Now, Give Permission to this Folder as 777.

```
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```